# How javascript try...catch statement works

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I am trying to test in browsermob if certain input field work or not. I am attempting to use a try...catch statement which I have never used before. I know that the form is:

```
try {
//some code
} catch (){
//some error code
};
```

What exactly is supposed to be put in the parenthesis after the catch statement?
When I try to use the statement it runs everything through the catch statement no matter if it is not an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [“`try...catch` statement” guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#try...catch_statement).

In short, try/catch is used to handle exceptions (which are "thrown" using the `throw` statement). The syntax for try/catch is:

```
try {
    // Code
} catch (varName) {              // Optional
    // If exception thrown in try block,
    // execute this block
} finally {                      // Optional
    // Execute this block after
    // try or after catch clause
    // (i.e. this is *always* called)
}
```

`varName` is available to the scope of the `catch` block only. It refers to the exception object which was thrown (which could be any type of object, e.g. a `String`, but is usually an [`Error` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is making more sense now. So the parenthesis after catch holds the variable that is the errors?

Comment: the catch identifier doesn't really need to be unique (I think that's JSLint stuff), when the `catch` statement runs, the scope is augmented, an object that contains a property named like the identifier is added to the scope chain, if another identifier existed in scope with the same name, it will be simply shadowed inside the `catch` block.

Comment: @CMS, Okay, maybe it was JSLint telling me things.  (I use JSLint in my build process.)  I remember something erroring when I had two try/catch statements and the catch statements had the same variable name.  I'll edit my post to exclude that statement, though, as it's not really necessary.

Comment: Note: This functionality is not part of the ECMAScript specification.

Answer (score 4):

The try catch statement is used to detected for exceptions/errors that are raised inside the `try`-block. In the catch block you can then react on this exceptional behavior and try to resolve it or get to a safe state.

You got the statement almost right:

```
try {
 // code that may fail with error/exception
} catch (e) { // e represents the exception/error object
 // react
}
```

Consider the following examples:

```
try {
  var x = parseInt("xxx");
  if(isNaN(x)){
    throw new Error("Not a number");
  }
} catch (e) { // e represents the exception/error object
 alert(e);
}

try {
 // some code
 if(!condition){
   throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
 }
} catch (e) { // e represents the exception/error object
 alert(e);
}
```

Comment: so you don't necessarily need to have the finally statement?

Comment: yes finally is an optional part of the statement that guarantees that the code inside it is executed regardless there was an exception or not.

Answer (score 2):

the stuff inside try {...} is what you want to execute.  The stuff in catch() { ... } is what you want to execute if you get any javascript errors from anything executed in the try {...}

catch {...} only executes if there is a javascript error in the try {...} block. You can find out what the error is by doing for example this:

```
try {
 // do something 
} catch (err) {
  alert(err);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to `ECMAScript` specifications,

```
try {
    // Code
} catch (varName) {  // optional if 'finally' block is present.
  if (condition) {   // eg. (varName instanceof URIError)
    // Condition (Type) specific error handling
  }
  else {
    // Generic error handling
  }
} finally {          // Optional if 'catch' block is present.
    // Execute this block after
    // try or after catch clause
    // (i.e. this is *always* called)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code that is likely to throw an exception goes into `try { }`, The code to be run when an exception is thrown, comes into `catch() { }`. In catch() you can specify which exceptions you want to catch, and in which automatic variables to put it.
`finally { }` is always run, regardless whether exception was thrown or not.